# Google Spreadsheet Api set color of a cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Data api's ListEntry to write value to Google worksheet.
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/data

```
 val row = new ListEntry()
 row.getCustomElements().setValueLocal(
      "email", email)
```

I wonder if it is possible to also give color to the cell as well.

---

Comment: Not possible - google-apps-script is the only way I know of. While it is messy, you can call google-apps-script using a URL. use HTML service. - There is also the opensource google like spreadsheet - ethercalc

Comment: API v4 can be used to set background colour to cells...

https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#color

I am using the API to update / apply conditional formatting rules... your mileage may vary